# How to have nodejs server publicly accessible through public ip

Tags: node.js, ip

I've searched long and far, from some npm packages, to a third party forwarder like `ngrok`
I don't care about what way, mannerism, or tactic you use to do this, but how, on earth, do you have your nodejs server accessible by your public ip? Just note, that this answer must be able to be done by just running a program, and it must make your public ip be accessible. I ask for this because I want to have an app, that has this characteristic, so it must be automated to some programs executing. Tell me if it's impossible :(

Comment: I know your public ip does a ```nat``` to your device, and also I keep hearing talk of binding your IP to the public IP. If you have **any** method of doing any of these 2, I don't care about conditions on this one, I would give you correct

Comment: What do you mean by "public" IP? You mean a domain like `google.com` or a IP that I can connect to like `123.123.123.123`?

Comment: Yes, the one where you go to ipinfo.com and see your Ipv4, yup

Comment: Then if you go on google and serach `ip`, that should be a ip that is public, therefore if you setup port forwarding to your server then I will be able to connect to your server through the ip that google or ipinfo.com gives you. You'll want to be extra careful here because giving someone your ip can result in getting hacked, so you'll want a firewall.

Comment: So i can listen to this long IP?

Comment: This long IP is *your* IP. If you setup port forwarding, then anyone you give the IP to will be able to connect to your server through that IP.

Comment: the thing is, that piping, requesting and returning, all syntax methods fail me. The closest is to if I search example.com, I could get it to proxy through my server, but, obviously If I try the site outside from my network, makes no sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208950/discussion-between-sportzpikachu-and-the-bomb-squad).

Comment: As questions like this have been asked many times before, this has typically been marked as "off-topic" for stackoverflow because it's really about network configuration and not about coding.  The probable answer is that you set up port forwarding in your router/firewall so that requests arriving at your public IP on a specific port number, are forwarded through the firewall to a specific host on your local network.  Be very aware that this means that host/port/server must be safeguarded against random internet attacks because it will be open to them.

Comment: I am asking how to do this in coding, and not network configuration. Are you saying it's impossible?